# Pass a button with click handler via slot to recursive child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've got a page template with the following code part:

```
        <nested-draggable v-bind:list="list" v-bind:selected="selected" v-bind:group="dragGroup">
            <slot>
                <v-icon v-on:click="$root.$emit('click', el)" small v-if="allowcreate" style="float: right">mdi-plus</v-icon>
            </slot>
        </nested-draggable>
```

the sub component ("nested-draggable.vue") for the recursion looks like this:

```
<template>
    <ul class="tree">
        <draggable
            class="dragArea"
            tag="li"

            v-for="el in list"

            v-bind:elementdata="el"
            v-bind:key="el._id"
            v-bind:list="list_empty"
            v-bind:selected="selected"
            v-bind:group="group"

            v-on:add="add"
            >
            <span v-bind:class="{'selected' : el._id === selected._id}" v-on:click="elemClicked(el)">{{ el.title }}</span>

            <slot></slot>

            <!-- render children of the current iterated element -->
            <nested-draggable
                v-bind:list="el.children" v-bind:selected="selected" v-bind:group="group">
                <!--<slot></slot>-->
            </nested-draggable>
        </draggable>
    </ul>
</template>
```

so I'd like to have the click event from the button within the passed slot emited with the current iteration's var "el" when the "plus" button is clicked, but within the slot the "el" var that is used within the iteration at the nested-draggable component can not be accessed. Vue tells that there is no "el" reference when trying to emit. (Throwing this error: https://pastebin.com/8bNwMcDr)

So how can I access the recursive data within the passed slot? How do I have to define my slot when passing it?

The only solution I found is putting the button/event-link directly into the nested-draggable component (not as slot) but I think to be clean and write a nice separated component, this would not belong into the nested draggable component, but in its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass your event from the template because you can get in your method anyways. [This](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) should help you out.

Comment: I do not need the event. I need the iteration element (with the name "el") from the iteration within the recursive sub component.

Comment: In that case you will need to bind `el` to your slot to be able to access it inside the slot. Read more at  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots

Comment: You can do something like `<slot :el="el"> ... </slot>`

Comment: I tried this. This does not change a thing - "el" can still not be accessed within the slot

Comment: Can you post the exact code that is giving the error. The above is not clear enough.

Comment: the exact error looks like this: https://pastebin.com/8bNwMcDr - the part that is causing the error is written within the first part of my initial question: `<v-icon v-on:click="$root.$emit('click', el)" small v-if="allowcreate" style="float: right">mdi-plus</v-icon>`